# How to update custom paragaph which is added to User Profile?

Tags: 8, users, updating, paragraphs

I have a requirement to create/update a paragraph which is added as a custom field in USER profile. After surfing here, i got how to update a paragraph which is connected to node. But I am not able figure out for User profile. Any help will be appreciated. I used below code for saving the paragraph, but how it will linked to `$user->save();` ?

```
$paragraph = Paragraph::create([
      'type' => 'mmodule_paragraph',
      'field_employee_id' => 'Field value',
      'field_location' => 'Field value',
      'field_name' => 'Field value',
      'field_segment' => 'Field value',
    ]);
    $paragraph->save();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't save the paragraph, add it to the user field and then save it together with the user:

```
$paragraph = Paragraph::create([
  'type' => 'mmodule_paragraph',
  'field_employee_id' => 'Field value',
  'field_location' => 'Field value',
  'field_name' => 'Field value',
  'field_segment' => 'Field value',
]);
$user->field_paragraph[] = $paragraph;
$user->save();
```

In case you want to replace the field content overwrite the entire field array:

```
$user->field_paragraph = [['entity' => $paragraph]];
```

Comment: Thanks. Too small.. too good..

Comment: Hi @4k4, I have one more query regarding same. Before adding values to this field i need to delete if any values exists. Can you please help in this regard?

Comment: The field works like a php array, see the revised answer.